# jquery select element inside a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select an anchor inside a div like this

```
<div class="response content">
  Disapproved Bank Mandiri<br><br>
  <p>
    <a class="showlist" href="#">Back to list?</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

What is the jquery to do this ?

Comment: you should have read selectors ( http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ ) in jQuery before asking.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Any anchor in a div with "response" and "content" classes:

```
$('.response.content a')
```

Or only anchors with a class of "showlist":

```
$('.response.content a.showlist')
```

Answer (score 11):

If you require both classes on the `DIV`:

```
$("div.response.content a.showlist");
```

If not,

```
$("div.response a.showlist");
```

To learn more about basic usage of jQuery Selectors, visit http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 4):

Another way you could solve this is using jQuery [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Here is an example of using find() to select all  elements in a div with the class "response content".

```
jQuery('.response.content').find('a');
```

This is also a helpful post that visits the topic of [selectors vs. .find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230266/jquery-single-selector-vs-find)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$('.response').find('a');
```

Or

```
$('.response').find('.showlist');
```