# jQuery single selector vs .find()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Which is better to use as a performance perspective:

```
$(".div1 h2, .div1 h3")
```

or

```
$(".div1").find("h2, h3")
```

Comment: To find that out you could profile your code: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12177876/323407) for a non-performance-related but important difference. Personally I wouldn't worry about microsecond differences unless the code will run in a loop or you are writing a library which will be used by third parties.

Comment: the problem is often the same, 10⁶ x 1microsec makes 1sec :)

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/ (this logic can also be applied to native selectors)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The answer to your question is: yes.

**Don't worry about the performance difference, unless your code is slow**. If it is, use a profiler to determine bottlenecks.

From an analysis standpoint:

```
$(".div1 h2, div1 h3")
```

should be faster as jQuery will pipe it through `querySelectorAll` (if it exists) and native code will run faster than non-native code. It will also save on an additional function call.

```
$(".div1").find("h2, h3")
```

is better if you plan on chaining some other functions on `.div1`:

```
$(".div1").find("h2, h3").addClass('foo').end().show();
```

Comment: "slow" to me means more than approx `0.3s` for most JS functions. There's no way I'd let the browser hang for 1s, much less 10. If it passes my "slow threshold" I'd refactor the code and analyze performance.

Comment: Yes, you are right, in this case performance difference isn't a big deal. But be careful with that sentence. I am kinda traumatized for seeing several performance issues and people thinking "if it works I don't care any more"...

Comment: what I meant by my statement was that you shouldn't worry about performance unless it is a problem. I never said sloppy code was ok, but I don't mind an O(n^3) set of loops if they are understandable and aren't causing performance issues. If they did, I'd certainly work to reduce them to as close to O(n) as possible.

Comment: @BrunoLM: I agree about being careless. There is no harm in obtaining good habits and if they happen to increase performance not matter how small even beeter. Making something a good habit does not increase development time but does save time on performance tuning later if it is required.

Answer (score 50):

http://jsperf.com/selector-vs-find-again

selector is faster

(NOTE: made up random html just so it wasn't just those elements on the page)

Comment: This is the actual answer; instead of just "it doesn't matter". It matters because OP asked.

Comment: do you have any element about what makes it faster ? I would have instinctively thought the find to be faster. So I'm curious what makes it slower.

Comment: @Ar3s zzzzBov's answer mentions it.  If a browser supports `querySelectorAll` that will be used and that is faster.

Comment: Great job... Really proves which one is faster.

Comment: I got this... 
`selector` - 35,349 - ±1.47% - 43% slower
`find` - 62,415 - ±2.58% - fastest

With the other test( http://jsperf.com/single-selector-vs-find ) where it has `.hide()` chained, I got almost opposite.. find being 52% slower.. Can someone explain?

Comment: Using simple selectors is the fastest, even if it requires combining.
http://jsperf.com/selector-vs-find-again/52

Comment: Actually find is faster according to this test in the most current version http://jsperf.com/selector-vs-find-again/60 especially in simple finds

Comment: @nilveryboring It's still the same for the original selector in the question.  interesting that it's different with a simpler selector.

Comment: Okay, but what if we already have "```var $myVariable = $('.div1');```" for some other requirement(s), would "`$myVariable.find('h2, h3')`" be faster than full-selector?

Comment: Now .find() is faster. Check the official doc: https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

Comment: @Blodhgard I wonder where in that documentation you've found that .find() is faster. Here https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/#save-calls-to-queryselectorall it says to just use the single selector as it will reduce querySelectorAll() calls.

Answer (score 17):

Actually, .find() *CAN* be faster.

Selectors seem to be quicker over find when trying to select multiple elements; however, if you use a $.find, or even cache the descendant, you can see it's much faster:
http://jsperf.com/selector-vs-find-again/11

I also beg to differ about performance not being important. In this world of smart phones, battery life is king.

Comment: This is interesting, but in this case it will not search for the `h2` and the `h3` that are only descendant of `div1`.

Comment: @Dan The "find cache" actually uses div1, but just caches it above like: `var cache = $(".div1");`

That being said, Firefox doesn't seem to think that one is faster. In that case, you're correct, the "speed find" will find all `h2` `h3`, but it's simple to give them classes directly like: `$.find(".classh2, .classh3")` to target specific ones.

Answer (score 2):

I've just found this answer and want to add some numbers here, may be someone find them helpful and curious. In my case I looked for fastest `jQuery` selector for unique element. I don't like to add IDs without reason, so I looked for way to select elements without ID.

In my small research I used awesome [selector profiler](https://github.com/osteele/jquery-profile) for jQuery. And here is the code I fired up directly from Chrome console after I added profiler's library code:

```
$.profile.start()
// Lets 
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

  // ID with class vs. ID with find(class)
  $("#main-menu .top-bar");
  $("#main-menu").find(".top-bar");

  // Class only vs element with class
  $( ".top-bar" );
  $( "nav.top-bar" );

  // Class only vs class-in-class
  $( ".sticky" );
  $( ".contain-to-grid.sticky" );
}
$.profile.done()
```

Here are results:

```
jQuery profiling started...
Selector                  Count  Total Avg+/-stddev  
#main-menu .top-bar       10000  183ms 0.01ms+/-0.13 
nav.top-bar               10000  182ms 0.01ms+/-0.13 
.contain-to-grid.sti...   10000  178ms 0.01ms+/-0.13 
.top-bar                  10000  116ms 0.01ms+/-0.10 
.sticky                   10000  115ms 0.01ms+/-0.10 
#main-menu                10000  107ms 0.01ms+/-0.10 
undefined
```

*Slowest* selectors are on the top of this chart. Fastest ones are at the bottom. Surprisingly for me right after selector by ID i.e. `$('#main-menu')` I've found single class selector e.g. `.top-bar` and `.sticky`. Cheers!