# Difference between $(Parent Child) and $(Parent).find(Child) (in jQuery)

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery single selector vs .find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230266/jquery-single-selector-vs-find)

Is there any difference between $(Parent Child) and $(Parent).find(Child) in jQuery?

You may have multiple children like:

`$("div").find("span")` which will return all the children spans. But isn't it the same with `$("div span")`?

Comment: The other post only discuss performance-wise differences, so why is this a duplicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One very important difference is that `$` is overloaded with several meanings and as a consequence vulnerable when used with user-defined strings, while `find` is not.

E. g.

```
$('.items .'+location.hash.substr(1)) // very bad idea
$('.items').find('.'+location.hash.substr(1)) // this is OK
```

Comment: That is interesting. Could you elaborate on the vulnerability, maybe with an example is possible? We are using the first syntax a few times in our code and I would be interested in those vulnerabilities.

Comment: +1 @FrançoisWahl. I, stylistically, would prefer to do `$('.'+location.hash.substr(1), '.items')` but regardless, I'm having a hard time imagining what kind of vulnerability there is

Comment: See [jQuery bug #9521](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9521) for details; unfortunately, the jQuery team was quite half-assed in dealing with the issue.