# Find UL from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div **"editableDiv"** which is nested inside another div. **editableDiv** has an unordered list as its child item.
Please go through the code

```
<div>
    <div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true">
        <ul id="suggestUL"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Question is, how to find the innermost ul *suggestUL*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Select it by it's id ?

Comment: you have only one UL, and that UL is given an id. Whats the issue here?

Comment: Stupid me. Referenced by id and works. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you can find it by ID ( which should be unique).

```
$('#suggestUL');
```

2) *assuming* there is no ID and you want to find the innermost UL :

> how to find the **innermost** ul

```
<div>
    <div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true">
        <ul ></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this  :

```
$('#editableDiv ul:last');
```

Comment: <- Thanks. And now, How can I set its (**suggestUL**) css attributes. My code seems to be not working. Here it is `$('#suggestUL').css('left', pos.left + 'px');
        $('#suggestUL').css('top', pos.top + 'px');`

Comment: @BasavarajMetri How do you calculate `pos` ? ( and what `position` you have on it)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I got it. Had problem in `'pos.left'` and `pos.top`, fixed. Thanks Royi.

Answer (score 5):

You can get ul directly through `id` using id selector as id is supposed to be unique but you can use descendant selector as well

Using id selector

```
$('#suggestUL')
```

Use descendant selector

```
$('#editableDiv ul');
```

Answer (score 1):

Also using **`.find()`**

```
$('#editableDiv').find('ul');
```

Answer (score 1):

Most proper way to find ul element inside of div with jQuery is as following:

```
$('div#editableDiv').find('ul')
```

Read about selector performance related information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230266/jquery-single-selector-vs-find).

Answer (score 1):

You can find out this by way, using div id .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#editableDiv").find('ul');
    $("#editableDiv").find('ul').text("sss");
    console.log($("#editableDiv").find('ul'));
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mz_arain08/uZExr/)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have tagged this question with css I thought I would add an answer showing you that you can style it simply in css like this..

`#suggestUL { // Your Styling }` or `#editableDiv ul { // Your Styling }`

It depends what you want to do with the UL, your question of 'how to find the innermost ul' could be interpreted in a few ways.. perhaps you should consider improving your question?