# Selecting element from variable with class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a group of items like this:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="special"></li>
</ul>
```

and I have a jquery variable which is:

```
item = $('ul li')
```

how do I select the 'li' with the special class, using the variable. So that I could for example do something like this:

```
$(<item with special class>).click();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the elements are at root level, meaning it's the LI that has the class, not any of it's children, you would filter the collection against that selector.

```
var item    = $('ul li')
var special = item.filter('.special')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use selector like this

```
var item = $('ul li.special')
```

Comment: is $('ul').find('li.special') a tiny bit faster?

Comment: @Huangism do a speed test and let us know

Comment: interesting post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230266/jquery-single-selector-vs-find