# How to get the <td> tag from table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with several rows and this is how one of the rows look like:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="entry_karma" id="entry_karma_9">
            <h4>4</h4>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" id="vote_up_9" name="vote_up_9" onclick="vote(9, 'up', 1, 8);" disabled="disabled">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" id="vote_down_9" name="vote_down_9" onclick="vote(9, 'down', 1, 6);">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        </button>

    </td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>2014</td>
</tr>
```

I want to get the value of the `div` inside the first `td` in this `tr`. I have buttons in the same `td` and when I click them I go to a function and I need access to the row in that function.

I have tried the following

```
console.log($(this).closest("tr"));
console.log($(this).closest("tr").find(".div"));
```

but I keep getting

```
[prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: undefined]
```

I want to access to this row and the access to the previous and next row as well but I am not able to see where I'm going wrong here.

Thank you.

Comment: Replace this code console.log($(this).closest("tr").find(".div")); with
console.log($(this).closest("tr").find(".entry_karma"));

Comment: When you say you want to get the value of the div, do you mean 4 or <h4>4</h4>?

Comment: *I want to get the value of the div inside the first td in this tr* ::`$(this).closest('tr').find('td:first div').html()`

Comment: I want to get the 4 or <h4>, either would do.

Comment: $(this).parents('tr') will get you the row. $(this).parents('td').find('div > h4').text() should get you 4

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `.div` with `div`, and find the closest `td` since the button is already inside the first `td`, like so:

```
console.log($(this).closest("td").find("div"));
```

P.S.: If you use `.closest('tr')`, it will find all existing `div`s (if you have more than one).

Answer (score 1):

Its not `.div`. Its just `div`. `.div` refers to an `element` with class `div`. so you have to refer either just `div` or `div` with class `entry_karma`

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("div.entry_karma");
```

**Update**

Try

```
$(this).closest("tr").find(".entry_karma>h4").text();
```

To get the value you need to do what @wahwahwah said and to get `previous` and `next` `tr` you can do it as below:

```
var prevTr=$(this).closest("tr").prev();
var nextTr=$(this).closest("tr").next();
```

Comment: I get [prevObject: m.fn.init[0], context: undefined, selector: "div.entry_karma"].

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for element with `class="div"`, but there is nothing like that.

```
console.log($(this).closest("tr").find("div"));
```

Value (or better, content) of this div is in `.html()`, or `.text()`.

```
console.log($(this).closest("tr").find("div").html());
```

Answer (score 1):

You havn't defined any class name div.
Try like this:

```
console.log($(this).closest("tr").find("div:first"));
```

Comment: I get this [prevObject: m.fn.init[0], context: undefined, selector: "div:first"].

Comment: This is selecting div. if you need value you need to call funcation $(this).closest("tr").find("div:first").val();

Comment: instead of .val() use .text();

Comment: when I use text(), the console print a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parent-child selector in jQuery that includes the element and the class:

```
var child = $('td > .entry_karma');
```

`child` now equals `<h4>4</h4>` where you can then retrieve the html and get `4`

To get the parent `<tr>` element you can use the jQuery `.has()` selector using the same variable in the above `var child = *` snippet :

```js
var child = $('td > .entry_karma');

console.log(child.html());

// get parent tr
var parent = $('tr').has(child);

console.log(parent.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="entry_karma" id="entry_karma_9">
        <h4>4</h4>
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" id="vote_up_9" name="vote_up_9" onclick="vote(9, 'up', 1, 8);" disabled="disabled">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
      </button>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" id="vote_down_9" name="vote_down_9" onclick="vote(9, 'down', 1, 6);">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
      </button>

    </td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>2014</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or, if the value is always going to be nested in the `<h4>` tag, you can access it directly like this:

```
var val = $('td > .entry_karma > h4').html();
```

```js
var val = $('td > .entry_karma > h4').html();
console.log(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="entry_karma" id="entry_karma_9">
            <h4>4</h4>
          </div>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" id="vote_up_9" name="vote_up_9" onclick="vote(9, 'up', 1, 8);" disabled="disabled">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
          </button>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" id="vote_down_9" name="vote_down_9" onclick="vote(9, 'down', 1, 6);">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
          </button>

        </td>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>2014</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can get the next tr or the prev tr and get there div value? BTW, this is the only answer that worked so far.

Comment: @Pete - I've updated my answer... it's not that the other answers don't work it's that they're returning an "object in memory"  that *shouldn't* be parsed directly to a "string" in the console. Although, my answer moves around the DOM [*a little bit less*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230266/jquery-single-selector-vs-find) than the other answers (to my understanding.)

Answer (score 1):

In the button click handlers you can use the following for current, next, and previous rows, and the contents of the `div`:

```
var thisROW = $(this).closest('tr'),
    nextROW = thisROW.next(),
    prevROW = thisROW.prev(),
    div = $('div.entry_karma', thisROW).html();
```

```js
$('button[id^="vote_down_"]').on('click', function() {
    var thisROW = $(this).closest('tr'),
        nextROW = thisROW.next(),
        prevROW = thisROW.prev(),
        div = $('div.entry_karma', thisROW).html();
    console.log( thisROW[0], nextROW[0], prevROW[0], div.trim() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="entry_karma" id="entry_karma_9">
            <h4>4</h4>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" id="vote_up_9" name="vote_up_9" onclick="vote(9, 'up', 1, 8);" disabled="disabled">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" id="vote_down_9" name="vote_down_9" onclick="vote(9, 'down', 1, 6);">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        </button>

    </td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>2014</td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```