# jQuery $('#submitForm').find('form') vs jQuery $('#submitForm form')

Tags: jquery, find

I was wondering which of both methods is faster:

Selecting the container and the form itself at in one statement:

```
jQuery $('#submitForm form')
```

or using jQuery's .find() selector:

```
jQuery $('#submitForm').find('form')
```

Comment: Pretty sure the 2nd one but you could set up a benchmark on jsperf.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery single selector vs .find()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230266/jquery-single-selector-vs-find)

Comment: jsperf http://jsperf.com/find-vs-selector-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.find()` approach is faster because the first selection is handled without going through the Sizzle selector engine – ID-only selections are handled using `document.getElementById(`), which is extremely fast because it is native to the browser.

So

```
jQuery $('#submitForm').find('form')
```

Is Faster than

```
jQuery $('#submitForm form')
```

Selector optimization is less important than it used to be, as more browsers implement `document.querySelectorAll()` and the burden of selection shifts from jQuery to the browser.

Comment: Well for me it looks like .find is faster (even many others say it's slower). It's always about 20% faster than the single selector

Comment: Filtering by traversing it takes a bit more code, but it’s faster.

Comment: I would only say _Be specific on the right-hand side of your selector, and less specific on the left._ :)