# Find vs Selector speed in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table which contains many rows. I need to find the td data using jquery.
There are many ways to get that data

```
1. $("table tr td").each(function(){})

2. $("table").find("tr").find("td").each(function(){})
```

Now I want to know which method in better and why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6230394/2270492

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do profiling using `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` will give you ther performance in microseconds .

```
console.time('withSelector');
   for(var i=0; i<10E4 ;i++)
      $("table tr td");
console.timeEnd('withSelector');
```

the same for  `$("table").find("tr").find("td")` .. Run snippet below

## Result

[image]

## Analysis :

`With selector` is better than `find`

```js
function withSelector() {
   $("table tr td");
}



function withFind() {
   $("table").find("tr").find("td")
}

function run(fn, times) { 
   console.time(fn.name);
   for(var i=0; i<times ;i++)
      fn();
   console.timeEnd(fn.name);
}

run(withSelector, 10E4);

run(withFind, 10E4);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```